# How can I find out what reference software was used?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am working on a paper with someone who is out of email touch for a while. They used some reference software and I have no idea what it is. At least I *think* they did, as when I click on any part of the reference section, they are all automatically highlighted.

Is there any way to figure out what was used to create this so I can try to get it myself? I have tried endnote, but that doesn't seem to be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following approach: Right click on the references and toggle field codes. E.g. when Mendeley was used you can see something like `ADDIN Mendeley Bibliography CSL_BIBLIOGRAPHY`.

Comment: Wow it worked I got `{Addin ZOTERO BIB  blah blah blah}` Amazing. I told them not to delete my endnote library so annoyed but also happy now you solved this for me!